# Colorama / termcolor colored output not working completely

Tags: python, colorama, termcolor

I've got an issue in my code. I want to print to colored boards to the terminal of a fleet battle game.

This is my code:

```
# function to print the hole board while player is playing the game
def print_leaked_board(board):
    """
    function to print the board with visible ships
    Args:
        board (List): The board on which the ships are placed
    """
    # creates the first row with letters to locate the ship positon (horizontal)
    print("  ".join(letterRow))
    for i, row in enumerate(board):
        # creates the first column with letters to locate the ship positon (vertical)
        print(str(i + 1).zfill(2), end="  ")  # zfill to format number  (0digit)
        # replace function to optical replace 1 = ship position, 0 = free space (water), 6 = placement blocker for following player ships
        print(
            "  ".join(
                str(elem).replace("1", "\033[37m#").replace("0", "\033[34m~").replace("6", "\033[31mX")
                for elem in row
            )
        )


# function to print the hole board while player is placing the ships
def print_hidden_board(board):
    """Function to print the board without showing the ships, so the opponent cannot see the ships of the other player

    Args:
        board (List): The board on which the ships are placed
    """
    # creates the first row with letters to locate the ship positon (horizontal)
    print("  ".join(letterRow))
    for i, row in enumerate(board):
        # creates the first column with letters to locate the ship positon (vertical)
        print(str(i + 1).zfill(2), end="  ")  # zfill to format number  (0digit)
        # replace function to optical replace
        # 1 = ship filed but hidden (shown as water),
        # 2 = free space (water),
        # 2 = shot spot without hit,
        # 3 = shot spot with hit, 4 = eleminated ship (complete)
        print(
            "  ".join(
                str(elem).replace("1", "~").replace("0", "~").replace("2", "O").replace("3", "x").replace("4", "#")
                for elem in row
            )
        )
```

In the first function the colored output is working fine. In the second print function, which is basically the same as the one above, i only get the '7m#' printed and i don't know how to fix it. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can we see a byte-by-byte comparison of the strings being sent to `print`? One example of a working one, one example of a non-working one.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do that? @RandomDavis

Comment: No, but it's not that hard I'm sure, you'll have to use Google to figure it out. Maybe it's not that important. At least, though, just put the raw strings into your question, so we can compare them.

Comment: Make a [mcve] with `board` defined and the functions called.  Add the expected vs. actual output.